# How to handle any iterator without putting the code in the header file?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

Here is the problem:

Header file (part of a library's API):

```
template <typename IterType>
void foo(const IterType &begin, const IterType &end);
```

CPP file:

```
template <typename IterType>
void my_really_large_implementation_specific_function(const IterType &begin, const IterType &end) {
    // ...
}
```

Is is possible to make `foo()` call `my_really_large_implementation_specific_function()` without including `my_really_large_implementation_specific_function()`'s code in a header file and without making more than one instance of its template? Maybe using some kind of wrapper iterator class, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Do the value types of the iterator have a common base class?

Comment: Why use a template if you only want one instance?

Comment: The linker is smart enough that you will end up with only one instance of your function.

Comment: If you know all the types it will be used with you can define the templated function it in a cpp file and instantiate it for all the types. This will ensure the object code is created and will be available at link time.

Comment: @ipc : If by "value types" you mean the types iterated over, then yes.

Comment: @Peter Wood: I don't know what types will be used.

Comment: My idea is whether it's possible to create some kind of wrapper iterator that can wrap any iterator and be passed to any function that accepts only the wrapper iterator, if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your function to be able to operate on arbitrary iterator types then the body needs to appear in the header.

If you need to support only one iterator type then it doesn't need to be a template and can appear in the source file.

Answer (score 4):

Look here for an exemple using any_iterator that is included in Boost.Range : http://geek-cpp.blogspot.fr/2012/11/using-boost-anyiterator-to-hide.html

```
#include <string>
// note that there is no include to multi_index here! 
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/range/concepts.hpp>
#include <boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp>

class hidden_container; //forward declare the hidden container

class exemple {
public:
  boost::scoped_ptr<hidden_container> impl; //hidden container behind pointer

  // declare a type erased iterator that can iterate over any container of std::string
  // this could be a std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator or a     std::list<std::string>::const_iterator
  typedef boost::range_detail::any_iterator<
         const std::string,
         boost::forward_traversal_tag,
         const std::string&,
         std::ptrdiff_t
         > const_iterator;

  //ctor
  exemple();
  // abstracted iterators
  const_iterator begin() const;
  const_iterator end() const;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at [boost::any_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html)? It uses [type erasure](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) to hide template types with virtual method calls as a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you simply want to do a for_each?

```
// In the header:
void my_really_large_implementation_specific_function(const common_base_class& c);

template <typename IterType>
void foo(const IterType &begin, const IterType &end)
{
   std::for_each(begin, end, my_really_large_implementation_specific_function);
}
```